# How to create Schematic Attribute (ArcObject .Net api)

Tags: .net, arcgis, arcobjects, esri-arc-engine

I am writing an ArcCatalog(10.1) Addin(C#) for creating a schematic diagram template and Element Classes.
Now I need to create some attributes such as OriginNode and ExtrimityNode for Link class,
Constant and another field Attribute for other classes.

I have created the element classes like the following, could not manage to create a
*ISchematicElementClass emtClass = [ISchematicDataset].CreateSchematicElementClass(elmClassName, esriSchematicElementType.esriSchematicNodeType);*

Element Class Object has a method CreateSchematicAttribute("NodeName", uid) but can not manage, how to work with that....

It is giving an error "Item not found in the collection"

Can someone help ....

Thanks
Naym